# SQLAlchemy query execution throws "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I need to select rows from a MariaDB table with certain ids. For this, I created the following query and execution code with SQLAlchemy in Python:

```
stmt = (
    select(transactions_table).
    where(transactions_table.c.id.in_(df['transaction_id'].to_list()))
)

data_db = pd.read_sql(stmt, engine)
```

The corresponding `transactions_table` object looks like this:

```
transactions_table = Table(
    'transactions',
    metadata_obj,
    Column('id', String(8), primary_key=True),
    Column('issuer_id', ForeignKey('affiliates.id')),
    Column('mop_id', ForeignKey('mop.id')),
    Column('station_id', ForeignKey('stations.id')),
    Column('product_id', ForeignKey('products.id')),
    Column('transaction_time', DateTime),
    Column('contract_id', ForeignKey('contracts.id')),
    Column('quantity', Float),
    Column('displayed_turnover', Float),
    Column('applied_turnover', Float),
    Column('invoiced_turnover', Float),
    Column('invoice_id', ForeignKey('invoices.id'))
)
```

Strangely, up until a few days ago this used to work, whereas now I receive the following error:

```
Error loading preloads:
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

When I delete the where condition from the query, the query still runs without any problems and returns all rows from the database as expected.

The maximum stack size (`sys.getrecursionlimit()`) is set to 3,000. I tried increasing it but the error persisted.

I searched all over Google and StackOverflow but did not find any similar problems in combination with SQLAlchemy.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem occurs in both IPython and standard-Python via the console.

Answer (score 0):

The error means acutally that your error trace is too long, [see also this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10172)

Try `python filename.py 2> err.log` in the command line to catch the error.

Since your error trace is very long, I guess that your WHERE clause is very long. Have you tried to increase max_allowed_packet? For example in your config file:

```
[mysqld]

max_allowed_packet = 100M
```